# Chrome Autoplay Blocker stops my video

Tags: css, html5-video, autoplay

The autoplay background hero on my website recently stopped working due to Chrome's new autoplay blocker. There is no audio so I'm confused as to why...please assist.

www.homecareassistancemontreal.ca

Comment: I see you have incorporated @Andrzej's solution on your website; it would have been proper to acknowledge that over here.

Comment: My apologies. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stopped, because Chrome doesn't want any sound-generating videos to start without user's direct agreement (e.g. starting it). If you want video to autoplay you must ensure it is muted.

To do so you must add `muted` attribute to your `<video>`.

```
<video muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[You can read more about this here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_muted.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Videos must be muted.

```
<video muted>
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

One issue I recently come across with Chrome was that if you're adding Video elements via JavaScript and you're setting your muted attribute to `true`. Google will block playback if you're using `.setAttribute`. Use dot notation instead.

Bad

```
VideoElement.setAttribute('muted', true);
```

Good

```
VideoElement.muted = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a smart hack that will autoplay video with sound without any problem:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function (stream) {
    
    video.play(); // play your media here

    // stop microphone stream acquired by getUserMedia
    stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) { track.stop(); });
});
```

It will ask users for their Microphone permission (only first time in chrome) and they have to click Allow then you are permitted to play anything with sound. It works because as long as you are capturing anything then you are allowed to play everything and then stop the microphone stream when your media starts playing.